# Rails/Formtastic many-to-many ordered list HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I have a Post model with a many-to-many Category association.  In my Post form, I call `f.input :categories, :as => :check_boxes` and get a nice ordered list of check boxes.  Is there anyway to add a class to each `<li>` using the category's name (or any Category data)?

Example:

```
<li class="<%= category.name %>">...label and input...</li>
<li class="<%= category.name %>">...label and input...</li>
<li class="<%= category.name %>">...label and input...</li>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
f.input :categories, :as => :check_boxes, :value_as_class => true
```